# What is the first fighter jet aircraft which carried out a night bombing mission?

Tags: fighter, jet, night-flying

Does anyone know in which occasion it was carried out and  the date which it was carried out? Night bombing began in World War I and was widespread during World War II. A number of modern aircraft types are designed primarily for nighttime bombing, but air forces no longer refer to them as night bombers. More common terms today include interdictor and strike fighter, and such aircraft tend to have all-weather, day-and-night capabilities.

Comment: Are you asking about bombers? or fighters being used as bombers? or any military aircraft? I'm kind of confused why a fighter jet aircraft would be sent out on night bombing missions. Especially the first jet powered aircraft. There weren't a lot of dual-purpose aircraft in the very beginning of the jet age.

Comment: Hard to think of anything like that prior to the B-52 raids on Hanoi.

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE! Are you asking what was the first aircraft to carry out a night bombing mission? Or the first fighter to escort bombers on a night bombing mission? Or the first multirole combat aircraft used for night bombing? If you can make your question a little clearer you may get a better answer.

Comment: @JohnK - RAF Canberras were used in night raids during Operation Musketeer, the Anglo-French Suez operation in 1956.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey  Brilliant! That sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: Canberras weren't 'fighters'.

Comment: F80s carried out ground attack sorties in Korea in the early 1950s in the 8th Fighter-Bomber Wing and 49th Fighter-Bomber Group, I haven't found a record of any night missions but there may well have been - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_P-80_Shooting_Star#Korean_War